# Prevent cannot borrow `*self` as immutable because it is also borrowed as mutable when accessing disjoint fields in struct?

Tags: rust, borrow-checker

Prior question that this is not a duplicate of:

- [cannot borrow `*self` as mutable because it is also borrowed as immutable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26938162/cannot-borrow-self-as-mutable-because-it-is-also-borrowed-as-immutable)

  - This question is not relevant b/c the answer ended up being "the Rust compiler has a bug", which I'm pretty sure is not the case here.

I have the following structs:

```rust
struct Foo {
    data: Vec<Bar>,
    a: usize,
}

struct Bar {
    b: usize
}
```

Inside `impl Foo`, I have the following methods:

```rust
fn example(&mut self, c: usize) {
    let baz = &mut self.data[c];
    let z = self.calc(c);
    baz.b = 42 + z;
}

fn calc(&self, x: usize) -> usize {
    self.a * x
}
```

Of course, the Rust compiler throws an error saying roughly "a mutable borrow occurs when you create `baz`, then you do an immutable borrow when you call `self.calc` and lastly you later use the mutable borrow when you assign to `baz.a`.

However, I'm accessing disjoint fields on the struct because `calc` never reads from data that is being written to through `baz`.

Is there a way to inform the Rust compiler of this?

Comment: Pretty sure there isn’t. In the example code, you can move the declaration of `baz`, and realistic workarounds are going to be similarly case-specific. Do you have an example closer to your actual code in that respect?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is the signature of `Foo::calc`, which takes `&self` as the receiver. This *guarantees* to `calc` that there are no mutable references to all of `self`, including any of its fields; that is, all of `Foo` is guaranteed to be immutable from the body of `calc`'s point of view. This is not possible with the code as it is, because `self.calc(c)` requires to immutably borrow `self` (*all* of `self`) while a mutable borrow is still active.

The fact that `calc` never reads from data that is being written to `baz` is irrelevant. In Rust, all there is to know about a function or method is exposed in the signature; the compiler never looks "into" a function to figure out if it's a special case or not.

You can avoid the problem by not requiring `calc` to take `&self` as a receiver. For instance, by borrowing individual fields before the call (`Self::calc(&self.a, c)`) or, as in the example below, by not borrowing `self` at all:

```
impl Foo {
    fn example(&mut self, c: usize) {
        let baz = &mut self.data[c];
        // This avoids borrowing `self` in its entirety...
        let z = Self::calc(self.a, c);
        baz.b = 42 + z;
    }

    fn calc(a: usize, x: usize) -> usize {
        a * x
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I ended up doing:

```rust
fn example(&mut self, c: usize) {
    let baz = &self.data[c];
    // some stuff that requires reading `baz`
    let z = self.calc(c);
    let baz = &mut self.data[c];
    baz.b = 42 + z;
}

fn calc(&self, x: usize) -> usize {
    self.a * x
}
```