# Mutable and Immutable reference inside println

Tags: struct, rust, ownership

I am fairly new to Rust and encountered some beginner problems and want to share my solution with others around the internet that I haven't found in existing threads. I wonder if there is a more *Rust* approach to it.

I want to print out the height, width and area of a Rectangle.

```
struct Rectangle {
    height: u32,
    width: u32,
    area: u32,
}

impl Rectangle{
    fn area(& mut self) -> u32 {
        self.area = self.height * self.width;
        return self.area
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut rect1 = Rectangle {height: 20, width: 30, area: 0};
    println!("Rectangle has height {} width {} and area {}", rect1.height, rect1.width, rect1.area());
}
```

which gives me the error *cannot borrow as immutable because it is also borrowed as mutable*

```
error[E0502]: cannot borrow `rect1` as mutable because it is also borrowed as immutable
  --> src/main.rs:17:88
   |
17 |     println!("Rectangle has height {} width {} and area {}", rect1.height, rect1.width, rect1.area());
   |     -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------^^^^^^^^^^^^--
   |     |                                                       |                          |
   |     |                                                       |                          mutable borrow occurs here
   |     |                                                       immutable borrow occurs here
   |     immutable borrow later used here
```

My solution

```
println!("Rectangle has height {1} width {2} and area {0}", rect1.area(), rect1.height, rect1.width);
```

changing the order in the `println!` statement.

I know that you cannot have an immutable and mutable reference at the same time, because the immutable reference does not expect the values to be changed. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65545236/prevent-cannot-borrow-self-as-immutable-because-it-is-also-borrowed-as-mutabl). But why does my solution work? Clearly, there still is a mutable and immutable reference in the same `println!` statement but with changed order.

Comment: I have to say the sequence of borrows bit me a few times :) Rust has made some progress in that regard. And me too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> But why does my solution work? Clearly, there still is a mutable and immutable reference in the same println! statement but with changed order.

Nope! The thing is `area()` requires a mutable borrow *but does not keep one*, since it returns an owned value (`u32`) rather than a borrowed one (`&u32`), so the borrow only lasts for the extent of the call and is released once the call returns.

Now you could expect the same of `height` and `width`, the trap is that `println!` *implicitly* borrows its parameters, so when you `println!("{}", rect.height)` it compiles to something along the lines of `Arguments("", &rect.height)`, creating a borrow until the end of the formatting process.

Now because the borrow is implicit you can't deref' the attribute (`*rec.height`) as that would be `&*rec.height` where `rec.height` is still a u8, however there is an other method which is [*block expressions*](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/expressions/block-expr.html):

> Blocks are always value expressions and evaluate the last expression in value expression context. This can be used to force moving a value if really needed.

This means that `&{rec.height}` will first copy (or move) the value out of the structure, then borrow that copy. Therefore you can also fix the call by writing:

```rust
println!("Rectangle has height {} width {} and area {}", {rect1.height}, {rect1.width}, rect1.area());
```

That will copy the two attributes out first, then `println!` will implicitly borrow them, but it won't need to borrow the structure itself leading to three non-overlapping borrows.

In that case, you may want to add a comment to explain why you're doing that as it's... odd.

Then again, I think your `area` is an anti-pattern, so YMMV.

Comment: Well, it's not even an anti-pattern, more like anti-common-sense. I hope it's just a contrived example for this post. Area should be calculated either on construction (stored and ref), or on request (calculated on the fly returning new value, not ref)

Comment: @Rbjz In writing the comment I took area as a stand-in for some sort of lazy computation e.g. something expensive to compute so you wouldn't want to compute it if you never used it, but once computed you'd want to keep the value around. Hence calling it an anti-pattern. Area itself I agree makes no sense as it's a pretty cheap computation.